# Problems adding nodes

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, element

Right now I have

```
 doc = new XDocument(
        new XElement(xmlns + "displayMLResponse",
            new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.peek.se/DisplayML/"),
            new XAttribute("version", "1.12"),
            new XAttribute("dateTime", date),
            new XElement("getStatusResponse",
                new XElement("systemInformation",
                    systemInformationList.Select(info => new XElement("item",
                        new XElement("name", info.name),
                        new XElement("value", info.value))).Where(item => item != null)),
                responceList.Select(fault => responceList.Count != 0 ?
                    new XElement("faults",
                        new XElement("systemFault",
                            new XElement(fault.faultType,
                                new XAttribute("description", fault.description),
                                fault.name.Length == 0 ? new XAttribute("name", fault.name) : null,
                                fault.size.Length == 0 ? new XAttribute("size", fault.size) : null))) 
                    : new XElement("OK"))
                    )));
```

Problem is that the  `new XElement("OK")` wont be added if **responceList** is empty as it wont evaluate the things inside `responceList.Select(..)` as it is empty.

Cant get my head around the problem how I must do. 

Question is how to add either the elements **faults** if there are any otherwise add the element **OK**

I am trying to create:

```
<displayMLResponse xmlns="http://www.peek.se/DisplayML/" version="1.12"
dateTime="2001-12-17T09:30:47">
    <getStatusResponse>
        <systemInformation>
            <item>
                <name>Manufacturer</name>
                <value>PEEK</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <name>Version</name>
                <value>1.0.0</value>
            </item>
        </systemInformation>
        <OK/>
    </getStatusResponse >
</displayMLResponse>
```

**OK** is replaced by:

```
<faults>
    <systemFault>
        <missingTemplateFault name="templateAlfa"/>
    </systemFault>
    <systemFault>
        <missingFontFault name="arial" size="18"/>
    </systemFault>
</faults>
```

if there are any faults, in this case **responceList** is a list of faults

Comment: I am finding it hard to understand what's going on. Maybe pull some pieces of it into variables. Especially the ones around ?: operators.

Comment: new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.peek.se/DisplayML/") is redundant. You already have *XNamespace xmlns*.

Comment: .. and you need to add *xmlns +* to all element names.

Comment: Eaitherway I strip away xmlns so thoose are not any concern and this example works without them. And by adding xmlns at the start it automagicly adds those to the elements.

Answer (score 0):

responceList.Select(lamba) is a 'select function' that will be run _once for each item in responseList to decide if it is included in the output,  thus

```
fault => responceList.Count != 0 ? ...
```

will only run at ALL if responseList in non-empty, and is thus redundant.

I think you want:

```
            ...
            new XElement("value", info.value))).Where(item => item != null)), 
                 responceList.Count != 0 ?  responceList.Select(fault => 
                   new XElement("faults",
                       new XElement("systemFault",
                           new XElement(fault.faultType,
                               new XAttribute("description", fault.description),
                               fault.name.Length == 0 ? new XAttribute("name", fault.name) : null,
                               fault.size.Length == 0 ? new XAttribute("size", fault.size) : null))) 
                 : new XElement("OK"))
```

Ie you doing your defaulting outside the inner select so it does get called.

Comment: With that I get: Error 1 `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' and 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'`  on `new XElement("OK")`

Comment: Cast it to object, that should keep the compiler happy: (object)new XElement("OK")

Answer (score 0):

As I havnt goten any answer I add this as a workaround.

```
    doc = new XDocument(
        new XElement(xmlns + "displayMLResponse",
            new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.peek.se/DisplayML/"),
            new XAttribute("version", "1.12"),
            new XAttribute("dateTime", date),
            new XElement("getStatusResponse")));


    XElement ele = doc.Root.Element("getStatusResponse");

    if (systemInformationList.Count != 0)
    {
        ele.Add(new XElement("systemInformation",
                    systemInformationList.Select(info => new XElement("item",
                        new XElement("name", info.name),
                        new XElement("value", info.value))).Where(item => item != null)));
    }

    if(responceList.Count != 0)
    {
        ele.Add(responceList.Select(fault => 
                    new XElement("faults",
                        new XElement("systemFault",
                            new XElement(fault.faultType,
                                new XAttribute("description", fault.description),
                                fault.name.Length == 0 ? new XAttribute("name", fault.name) : null,
                                fault.size.Length == 0 ? new XAttribute("size", fault.size) : null)))));
    } else
    {
        ele.Add(new XElement("OK"));
    }
```